# Realising object dynamically 

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I have a connection class that uses NSURLConnection to connect to the server. While in main class I call a class method of this class, the class method then allocates instance of itself and when the delegate ConnectionDidFinish is received, I release same class from within. Is this approach correct or this will lead to some problem.

Main Class :

```
[ConnectionClass connectToServer];
```

Connection Class :

```
@implementation ConnectionClass
 +(void)connectToServer{
   connectionClass = [[ConnectionClass alloc] init];
   [connectionClass createConnection];
 }
 -(void)createConnection{
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
  // create asynchronous connection
 }
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
   [self release];
 } 
@end
```

Is it good to release self within its own method ?

What if I do it something this way;

Main Class :

```
[connectionClass setDelegate:self];
[connectionClass connectToServer];
```

Connection Class :

```
@implementation ConnectionClass
 -(void)connectToServer{
  [connectionClass createConnection];
 }
 -(void)createConnection{
  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
  // create asynchronous connection
 }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
  [self.delegate finishedConnection:self]; // added delegate and then called to the main class and pass the self object for main to release it
 } 
 @end
```

And in the main class delegate we, release the object,

```
-(void)finishedConnection:(ConnectionClass*)connection
{
  [connection release];
 }
```

IS there any problem in releasing the object this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
@implementation ConnectionClass

+ (void)connectToServer {

    connectionClass = [[ConnectionClass alloc] init];
    [connectionClass createConnection];
    [connectionClass release];
}

- (void)createConnection {

    [self retain];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    // create asynchronous connection
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [self release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self release];
}

@end
```

That way the `ConnectionClass` object is self retaining, and you're not putting the retain/release responsibility in different places of code, that are not tightly related.

**Edit:** As Rabskatran points out, if you're just learning about retain/release, then this is not the optimal solution.

Your second example with the delegate is better. I'd let the `connectionClass` object be an instance variable, so you can message the connection object to cancel the operation when the main class (which would be the connection's delegate) gets deallocated.

Comment: This isnt for learning purpose instead I am in a situation where  I could create multiple instances of it. But, I needed an easy approach to release it to avoid leaks. I could create connectionClass as global and then make use of it but I would have to keep track of the number of connections going and when all the connection finishes release it. But, this way I create a single instance for single connection and release it as it finishes.

Comment: The logic is that, from the point of view of the connectionClass object, someone has created "him". For a purpose that "he" doesn't know. This creator has implemented the protocol requested by the connectionClass class. It's not this connectionClass object that has to decide when he can leave the scene. Maybe the creator will want to access one of his property after the call of "connectionDidFinishLoading" method. It will be impossible if it's the connectionClass instance that decide when to kill himself. Anyway, I don't see why it's not easy to call [Myconnector release] within "DidFinish.."

Comment: @Rabskatran For everyday memory management, you're right. But in some cases it's a good idea for objects to retain and release themselves, especially asynchronous, background threaded operations that finish up with a callback. You really don't want a `NSURLConnectionDelegate` object to get released prematurely. For `NSURLConnection` you can prevent a crash by calling `cancel` on the connection object, but for a background thread that's in the middle of processing data, you can't necessarily cancel the operation, and you don't want to pull the rug from under it.

Answer (score 2):

[self release] & [self retain] sound totally crazy to me. It makes no sense at all IMHO.
And I don't see the point of making (void)connectToServer a class method !

Your second way is the way to go. You could also make one step of the two, creating a method like :

[connectionClass connectToServerWithDelegate:self];

Comment: `[self retain]` and `[self release]` is actually quite common. That's how e.g. a UIAlertView can stay alive until the user has tapped a button. It retains itself in `show` and releases itself after the user has tapped a button.

Comment: Ok, that's a framework trick but it won't help him (her) to get the concept behind retain and release, I mean the responsibility and ownership of an instance. Owning yourself is a very special case.

Comment: Agreed. Under normal circumstances objects don't own themselves, and the second example is better.